# Measure the time difference/run time between Start and End in Power BI

Tags: sql, powerbi, etl, data-analysis

I have an SQL data warehouse on my localhost. The data is loaded with an ETL project in SSIS.
In the DWH I have a Logging table that gets filed every time an etl process runs. The logging table then gets reported in a dashboard in power bi.
In the logging I have StartTime and EndTime (in datetime) of every etl process that ran. Some rows don't have an EndTime because the ETL failed there.

Now I am trying to make a measure in power bi that shows how long is the run time of each process in seconds.
I've tried the following but it's not working:

```
TimeDiff = DATEDIFF(('Logging view'[StartTime]),('Logging view'[EndTime]), SECOND)


TimeDiff = Duration.TotalSeconds(('Logging view'[EndTime])-('Logging view'[StartTime]))
```

Anyone an idea on how to measure the runtime here?

Comment: "not working": what did it means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the `DATEDIFF` function it is expecting two dates, and if you use it like that in a measure, you're passing two columns.

My advice is to create a calculated column in you power bi model and use that formula:

```
TimeDiffSeconds = DATEDIFF(('Logging view'[StartTime]),('Logging view'[EndTime]), SECOND)
```

And then your measure can be the sum of the `TimeDiffSeconds`

```
TimeDiff = SUM('Logging view'[TimeDiffSeconds]
```

If you don't want to create a calculated column, you need to change the measure to give you only one date, and not a column, for example:

```
TimeDiff = DATEDIFF(MIN('Logging view'[StartTime]),MAX('Logging view'[EndTime]), SECOND)
```